# can Apple watch stream music as standalone app

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

We have an iphone app which is used to stream Music and video and we are planning to develop a `Watchkit extension` for same. 
is it possible for `applewatch extension`  to stream music without iPhone, or
 say it is possible to do streaming music when you are not near to your iPhone. or
 Watch extensions are depends upon phone to make network calls.
before starting development we are confused .

Comment: The watch app is just storyboards that display data from your iPhone app. You don't run any code directly on the watch and the watch doesn't have any direct network connectivity

Comment: So , i Should design an watch interface for app and this will open parent application for any action triggered from watch , For example  select a song on watch and then it would be played on Phone.

Comment: @Vivek That's certainly doable. But you can't stream from the Watch.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible. You can't play a sound on the Apple Watch speaker. 
When you play a sound from the extension, it is played on the iPhone as the extension lives on the iPhone.

The only way to play a custom sound through the Apple Watch is to set a custom sound file for a notification but I don't think this fits your case.

Comment: but i have seen videos , apple watch has connectivity with bluetooth headphones.

Comment: I'm interested. Do you have a link?

Comment: BalestraPatrick is correct. There's no way to accomplish this with the current version of WatchKit. Of course, that doesn't mean that Apple can't do it, and perhaps we'll be able to do it in a future update.

Comment: http://9to5mac.com/2015/04/16/best-apple-watch-headphones-earphones/    i am not sure as don't have seen real watch.

Comment: Those headphones are just to listen to music that is stored by the built-in in Music app. WatchKit apps can't access accessories and the built-in speakers.

Answer (score 1):

As of watchOS 6, it is now possible to both build a standalone watchOS app and stream audio as well.